# Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed

Tags: java, solr, nutch

I am using Solr 5.4.1 and Apache Nutch 1.12. I am able to crawl data but in a final step to index in Solr I got following errors.

```
 SOLRIndexWriter
    solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance
    solr.zookeeper.hosts : URL of the Zookeeper quorum
    solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
    solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
    solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
    solr.auth.username : username for authentication
    solr.auth.password : password for authentication
SolrIndexer: deleting 1/1 documents
SolrIndexer: deleting 1/1 documents
Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:145)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:237)
```

Comment: Can you share additional logs for Nutch/Solr?

Comment: I have solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your index name is all lower case.

Check that your hbase_site.xml that the hbase.rootdir, hbase.data and hbase.zookeeper-data and the log file paths are correct.

Finally, make sure to copy hbase_site.xml into your nutch/conf directory. If you are running nutch 2.x do it before compiling with ant, or re-compile (ant clean, ant runtime) once it is there.